# What's the idiomatic way to turn a single char into a string in Java?

Tags: java, idioms

Right now I'm using the following to minimize boxed object creation:

```
String myString = "" + myChar;
```

Is this the idiomatic way to do it? (IMHO it feels a little awkward.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`String.valueOf`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(char)) is your friend:

- It works for every type so you can be consistent
- It's null-safe (for reference types)
- It says what you mean

I have a [very short article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/stringconv.html) on this subject, in fact.

Comment: And you won the race by two seconds... the Java tag sure is fast-moving!

Comment: This one has the nicer explanation too :)

Answer (score 4):

`String.valueOf(char)` or `Character.toString(char)` (the latter calling the former)